# WKInterfaceTable and cells in storyboard not display cells in runtime.

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I expecting create a static table with 3 cells (with contents). I create them in storyboard. However, in the runtime, the whole table is disappeared.

How to display table and cells like iOS storyboard's static table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it short , you can see it in
http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-create-table/

**1. Create a table**

each WKInterfaceTable row has a Table Row Controller , add elements(labels etc..) to your group

**2.Create a Custom Table Row Controller**

make sure to add an identifier to your row and create an IBOutlet for            your elements

**3.Create a Data Source**

create an array of  names,as you needed

**4.Load Table Data**

don’t forget to create an IBOutlet for your Table in the InterfaceController